# Nodejs get request

Tags: node.js

I use the js to render the following line of code in html

```
<p class=""><h4><a href="/users/user_profile?userp=' + this._creator._id +">+ 
 this._creator.username + '</a>
```

Then in node.js the following get request method

```
router.get('/user_profile',function (req,res) {
user_id = req.query.userp;
User.getUserById(user_id,function (err,user) {
if(err) throw err;
  res.render('user_profile',{
    user : user
  })
```

});
});
The code render to the selected user page but how can i just use one page for login user and selected user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You design a URL scheme that specifies a specific user's profile in a unique URL such as:

```
 http://somedomain.com/user/jackp/profile
```

And, then you create a handle for that specific URL layout in node.js.  One would usually use a framework such as Express to help you parse URLs so that you can create a single handler for `http://somedomain.com/user` and automatically parse the other two pieces of the above URL to give you the user name and the profile in the route handler.  But, if you aren't using such a framework, you can still make it work, you just have to do your URL parsing and matching.

There are many different possible URL schemes, for example, you could also use query parameters such as:

```
http://somedomain.com/profile?user=jackp
```

Comment: thanks very much that really work. I used node.js req.query to get the user id then redirect them to a profile page.

Comment: @adrian - if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community bt clicking the green arrow next to the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here.

Comment: In jquery/javascript i used the following to render the following html code       
    <p class=""><h4><a href="/users/user_profile?userp=' + 
    this._creator._id + '">' + this._creator.username + '</a>